# BIRT multi select parameter and where statement

Tags: sql, where-clause, birt

I'm trying to add a parameter to my report that will create a where clause like this...

```
WHERE 1 = 1
AND ((ID = id3 AND CLASS = class3) OR (ID = id1 AND CLASS = class1) OR (ID = id2 AND CLASS = class2))
```

The statement works when I run it in SQL NAV. Thisis is what I have in my BIRT report and it is giving me no errors just a blank report...

```
+ " WHERE 1=1 "
+ " AND ((ID = id3 AND CLASS = class3) " 
+ params["parameter"] 
+ " ) "
```

My parameters look like this...

```
VALUE                            | DISPLAY TEXT   
---------------------------------|------------- 
OR (ID = id1 AND CLASS = class1) | 1 
OR (ID = id2 AND CLASS = class2) | 2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong. Apparently BIRT does not like multi select lists. I found this out by testing a simple parameter and it still was not working. I ended up changing my code a little, changed the parameter to a Radio Button, and added a third parameter that was a combination of the first two parameters. It seems to be working fine now. Thanks anyways for the help Dominique!

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid to make use of SQL keywords in parameter values. This way would be better:

```
WHERE 1 = 1
AND ((ID = 3) OR (ID = ? AND CLASS = ?))
```

and then link these two query parameters to a report parameter having as datatype "integer" and possible values 1 or 2. These query parameters protect your report against possible SQLIA, unlike your current solution.

If you really have a good reason to build the query dynamically instead of using query parameters, then try a statement such:

```
WHERE 1 = 1
AND ((ID = 3) OR (ID = -1 AND CLASS = -1))
```

and in the beforeOpen script of the dataset:

```
this.queryText=this.queryText.replaceAll('-1', params["parameter"].value);
```

if "parameter" is an integer then the report is still protected against SQLIA.

Comment: Sorry my example wasn't a good example. I actually have a different value for the ID and the CLASS. I edited the example to reflect this. Thanks for the answer though. It would have worked if they were both the same.